# import two python packages with the same name for use in the same project

Tags: python, module, dependencies, package, dependency-management

I'm buiding an application that depends on `some_package` (which is rather large) as installed through `pip` or `conda`.  I would like to reuse parts of `some_package` directly in the application; to that end, I have forked `some_package`, installed it locally, and modified its functionality as needed. The application now depends on two (diverging) versions of the same package of the same name for different functionality.

How do I refer to the `pip`/`conda` managed `~/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/some_package/` for internal dependency, and the modified   `~/my_project/dependencies/some_package/` for use in my application?

There are several questions on Stack Overflow, but they are either quite old or not the same question:

- [Python: Two packages with the same name; how do you specify which is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197668/python-two-packages-with-the-same-name-how-do-you-specify-which-is-loaded)
- [Is it possible to use two Python packages with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062793/is-it-possible-to-use-two-python-packages-with-the-same-name?rq=1)
- [Importing from builtin library when module with same name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031584/importing-from-builtin-library-when-module-with-same-name-exists)

What I've tried:

- `conda develop <local package path>` : in this case, the site-package is not visible and breaks internal dependencies
- changing the name of the local package folder and importing: there are internal references to the package name that would mean renaming everywhere, and create a management mess if I ever wish to pull new code on the fork
- a comment suggested `import some_package as package_dev`: this obviously won't work as I have no way to refer to both packages in the first place

In the linked questions (and others), there are a number of hacks that will kind of work but break the import system in subtle ways (reload, for package updates, etc).  Is there a "pythonic"/recommended way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just import with different name: `import a as a_custom`

Comment: Why is it a management mess to rename the package? Can't you just do a find and replace of all the internal references?

Comment: recursively renaming `some_package` to `some_package_dev` and `conda develop project_name -n env_name` appears to have worked for now.